# How do I uniquely identify tab control?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I was planning to do something like this when certain condition is satisfied and the below code will run many times.

```
TabPage newtabcontrol = new TabPage();
tabControl1.Controls.Add(newtabcontrol);
```

But how do I know the tabIndex for the latest tabpage I just added?

Comment: Controls looks like a collection so you should be able to get the latest tabpage `var latestTab = tabControl1.Controls[tabControl1.Controls.Lenght-1];`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign `TabPage` a unique name

As for example

```
TabPage newtabcontrol = new TabPage();
newtabcontrol.Name = "ID-1";
tabControl1.Controls.Add(newtabcontrol);
```

And to find the `tabPage`, you can use

```
var tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages["ID-1"]
if (tabPage != null)
{
    // perform action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For last tabPage which added:

```
TabPage newtabcontrol = new TabPage();
tabControl1.Controls.Add(newtabcontrol);

TabPage temp = tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabCount - 1];
```